# Programming languages with IDE, fast compilation, popularity, static typing, performance, DRY

Tags: software-development, programming

Which programming languages have powerful IDE with good IntelliSense, fast compilation times, popularity, static typing, decent performance (not VM/interpreted), enough syntax sugar to minimize repetitive code, and not tied to web dev?

Comment: Honestly I suggest you to rewrite your question and focus on what's the most important feature / characteristics of the language to you. For instance, you can have a better IDE or IntelliSense through a third party software like Vscode + a IntelliSense extension. Note that different IntelliSense or linter extension can be focused on one or more languages.

Comment: If you are doing mostly technical computing I'd suggest looking at Julia (https://julialang.org/). It's dynamically typed, but is optionally typed so you get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stated needs, I would recommend that you go with Python.
Installing the SDK (software Development Kit) gives you access to not just the programming language but also a powerful IDE called IDLE, which you can immediately get productive with.

And if you don't like the IDE, there are so many free and open source IDEs you can use out there. I personally would recommend Visual Studio Code, since its lightweight, has good intellisense (with the right plugin installed) and is pretty fast.

Python is also a high level language with plenty syntactic sugar and inbuilt functions, which helps you avoid code repetition and helps with writing less code.

You can get the latest SDK download over here:
https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Does it use static typing? Isn't it interpreted?

Comment: Python uses dynamic typing so doesn't fit the OP's requirements. It is also interpreted although there are sort of ways of compiling portions of code.